# Write function that return data to datagridView in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am new with Entity Framework. My problem is I want to write a function that return a result query to DataGridView.

```
 public IEnumerable<tblCustomerType> GetCustomerType()
    {
       // IEnumerable<tblCustomerType> result;
        using (var context = new dbLMSEntities())
        {

           var  x = (from c in context.tblCustomerTypes
                     select new {c.CustomerTypeID, c.CustomerType}).AsEnumerable();
            return x;
        }
```

But I got and Error

> Cannot implicitly convert type `'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<AnonymousType#1>'` to `'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<LoanManagementSystem.tblCustomerType>'`

Comment: Why are you doing a `Select` rather than simply `return context.tblCustomerTypes.ToList()`?

Comment: I want select a specific Column only

Comment: @Ajaxta then change your function return type.

Comment: you need to inject the x into a new list of tblCustomer and return it

Comment: You didn't say that and the DataGridView is nowhere to be seen in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method returns a specific type:

```
public IEnumerable<tblCustomerType> GetCustomerType()
```

But you are selecting an anoymous type:

```
select new {c.CustomerTypeID, c.CustomerType}
```

Based on the naming, it sounds like your method just wants to return the records directly.  So there's no need to project into another type:

```
var  x = (from c in context.tblCustomerTypes
         select c).AsEnumerable();
return x;
```

Which can really just be simplified to:

```
return context.tblCustomerTypes;
```

Ideally your method would return an `IQueryable<tblCustomerType>` and itself not actually materialize any records.  Then if you have some other logic downstream which wants only a subset of the data then that's where you would perform that projection.  Defer the materialization of the data until you actually need it.

Comment: Thank you @David. Thank for your explanation

Answer (score 1):

```
public IEnumerable<tblCustomerType> GetCustomerType()
    {
       // IEnumerable<tblCustomerType> result;
        using (var context = new dbLMSEntities())
        {
            return context.tblCustomerTypes.ToList();
        }
}
```

Comment: Great, OK. Mark as answer if this fixes it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Change your function return type to IQueryable.

```
public IQueryable GetCustomerType()
{
   // IEnumerable<tblCustomerType> result;
    using (var context = new dbLMSEntities())
    {

       var  x = (from c in context.tblCustomerTypes
                 select new 
                 {
                     c.CustomerTypeID,
                     c.CustomerType
                 });
        return x;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Function return type is different than what you're trying to return.You have declared the function return type to return IEnumerable, while you're actually returning IEnumerable of an anonymous class.